# Add Speech to Text for Android App With Recognizer Intent or Keyboard Mic

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, speech-to-text, recognizer-intent

I've current got a RecognizerIntent up and running so that it returns a list of strings of possible sentences to me. However, I would like to improve upon this.

When I press on my Edit Text box, I can also press the "Mic" button on the keyboard which will also launch the speech to text. However, using the speech to text is much better this way because once the words are entered from the android keyboard, they are all highlighted and can be selected to choose a more accurate word. I've tried this on a few other phones as well and this behavior seems to be standard.

My question is, how can I use RecognizerIntent to have that same functionality. Are there additional parameters that I need to be setting to use it this way? Or is there a way for me to just "press" the mic button programmatically?